# Check if float result is close to one of the expected values

Tags: python, math

I have a function in Python makes a number of calculations and returns a float.

I need to validate the float result is close (i.e. +/- 1) to one of 4 possible integers.

For example the expected integers are 20, 50, 80, 100.

If I have `result = 19.808954` if would pass the validation test as it is with +/- 1 of 20 which is one of the expected results.

Is there a concise way to do this test? My python math functions are basic.

Comment: How would I use any() ? I would need an array of true/false values?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried this but it failed `result = 19.809894
next(result for result in [10, 20, 50, 80, 100] if abs(result - n) < 1)`

Comment: You called both the float and the `for` iteration variable `result` there, and I'm not sure what `n` is.

Comment: I don't know what n is either - you wrote the code?
I set result to be a example of the calculated result which should match one of the array values?

Comment: @AlGrant Try `result = 19.809894; next(r for r in [10, 20, 50, 80, 100] if abs(result - r) < 1)`

Comment: pytest has some helpers for this https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.approx might not be usable outside of unit tests though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
any(abs(actual - expected) < 1 for expected in [20, 50, 80, 100])
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This checks if the underlined boolean expression is true for any of the expected values. `any` will return as soon as it finds a true value and return `True` or `False` accordingly.

If you want to know *which* expected value it matches, change it to this:

```
[expected for expected in [20, 50, 80, 100] if abs(actual - expected) < 1]
```

This will build a list of matching values:

- If the list is empty, there was no match.
- If the list has one element, that's the match.
- In the edge case that there are multiple matches, the list will have multiple values. This could happen if the expected list had `19` and `20`, say, with an input of `19.5`.

Comment: @MarkRansom It depends on the expected values. 20, 50, 80, and 100 are just example values.